# send automatic email alert using stored procedure using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

`User` registered for one plan in website. The plan date is going to expire which means if 30 days, I have to send an automatic alert on the **21 st day** to the employer. I don't know stored procedures and all. Now only I am learning.

I don't know how to create a query for that. Using the query how to create in stored procedure and execute automatically to send an e-mail alert?

My linq query:

```
public bool GetDateExpired(int Id)
{
    var Subscribed = from om in _db.Order
                     join od in _db.OrderDetails on om.OrderId equals od.OrderId
                     where om.OrganizationId == Id && od.PlanName.Contains("plan") && od.OrderId == om.OrderId && om.PaymentStatus == true && od.RemainingCount > 0
                     select om;

    var count = Subscribed.FirstOrDefault();

    if (count != null)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

If this condition true means email send to the user. How to do this in a stored procedure? Please help me

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server provides a built-in method of sending emails via SMTP

You need to create a job in sql server agent, for details follow bellow link

[Click Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/sending-automated-job-email-notifications-in-sql-server-with-smtp/)